Requests to python development server hang/stuck before reaching the server
I am running a Django server locally using runserver_plus with --nothreading option.
Sometimes I send a request to any endpoint (from different clients, like the React frontend running in Google Chrome, Django admin, or Postman) and it takes a very long time to respond (usually 1.5+ minutes). Let's call the first request #1. While this request is being processed, if I open another tab and open any endpoints - thus, send request #2, the server immediately responds to request #2 and then immediately responds to request #1.
The processing of request #1 does not start executing until the processing of request #2 is finished.
To clarify: it is not a problem with the view related to request #1. I can't understand why the request processing does not start for a while. Here is the data from the django debug toolbar profiling. The processing itself seems to be fast, but this request took 1.5 minutes to start processing.

Django 4.2, Django extensions 3.2, DRF 3.15. The development server is run in docker-compose. MacOS Sonoma 14.4.

Based on your photo of Debug Toolbar, there was not a delay in Django rendering the page. Seems curious, can you show your code for #1? Also can you confirm that the load time was only slow on the first page loaded? -- if so, it might simply be the process of Docker starting

@ViaTech this is not related to a specific endpoint, so I don't think that code for #1 will help. It happens randomly (once every 3-4 requests) with all endpoints. Regarding your second point - no, it happens regularly, so I don't think that this is related to the process of Docker starting. Judging by the output of the debug toolbar, it feels like the request doesn't reach the server for some reason. Where could it get "stuck" between the client and the server? The development server is hosted on docker.

I looked for similar issues on StackOverflow. While I didn't find this exact problem, some MacOS users reported similar problems with Google Chrome. I tried switching to Mozilla Firefox and it seems to work fine. Even Postman works fine when I make requests after using Firefox, but it doesn't work fine after using Google Chrome.

hmm...this does not seem like a valid "fix" as clients of your system can use any browser they wish. Do you have weird cache settings in Chrome? What is the run console saying, is the request sent and then hangs or not sent? Glad you figured out a solution, but I'd suggest learning what caused it as I promise if it relates to production, you will hear about it in the future.

@ViaTech Not sure about Chrome settings, it's just a default configuration without any additional changes. Google's dev tools say that the request is sent, but the run console of the server does not mention the request, so it doesn't "arrive". I think I have noticed this on other websites as well - sometimes I need to click a link twice for it to open, so I don't think that it's specific to the python server that I run. But looking into the details of how this feature works is indeed a good idea. Will post an update if I find anything

The Google Chrome browser caused the issue in my case. It somehow affected requests sent with Postman after using Google Chrome. To test whether this is the cause of your problem, try switching to another browser and see whether the issue disappears.
I fixed this issue for Google Chrome by disabling the "Preload pages" setting on Google Chrome (chrome://settings/?search=Preload).
